# How to make a vertically extendable DIV box from this image?

Tags: css, html, background-image

I would like to create from this image a styled DIV box for my website :
[image]

How can I do that using CSS and HTML.

I cut the image in three different parts :

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

However I don't know how to use them with Divs to create my vertically expendable box.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with CSS3 features like border-radius,box-shadow and gradient. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4SARn/). Should work in Opera, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Also, you can do this with :before and :after CSS pseudo-elements, like in other two answers.

**Edit:** For Internet Explorer all those features are possible with behavior file, like [PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

Comment: @benjisail: you can use http://css3pie.com for rounded borders and drop shadow in IE.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want your content to start inside the top one, but expand to the second one as well. If that is the case then you will need some overlap on the background-images.

**HTML**

```
<div class="expandable">
    <div class="content top">content goes here</div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.expandable{
    background:url('middle-image.jpg') 0 0 repeat-x;
}
.top{
    background:url('top-image.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    height:auto!important;
    height:100px;/* whatever the height of the top (big) area is */
    min-height:100px; /* whatever the height of the top (big) area is */
}
.bottom{
    background:url('bottom-image.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    height:10px; /* whatever the height of the bottom image is. */
}
```

Example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/s8XZQ/

Comment: Thanks, it is the best non-CSS3 example! However I will try CSS3 with PIE.

Comment: @benjisail, you go with what is best for your case, and best for future maintenance. Css3pie seems to be the case ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="top"></div>
 <div class="middle">content here content here content here</div>
 <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { width: 300px; }
.top { padding-top: 15px; background: url(topimage.png); }
.middle { background: url(middleimage.png); }
.bottom { padding-bottom: 15px; background: url(bottomimage.png); }
```

Adjust the paddings in the CSS so that they match the height of your topimage and bottomimage, and the container width so that it matches the image's widths.

Comment: thanks, I had to modify it a little bit by adding a min-height:98px and a no-repeat for the .top. However with this solution how can I start writing my text at the top of the box and not 98px down?

Answer (score 1):

Use three separate divs, and set the top padding of the middle one to the minus height of the top one. So:

```
#top-div {
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(bg-top.jpg);
}
#middle-div {
  background-image: url(bg-middle.jpg);
  padding-top: -25px;
}
#bottom-div {
  background-image: url(bg-bottom.jpg);
}
```